# "First page" or "Page one" for SEO ranking?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-meaning, comparison

SEO is Search Engine Optimization.
I want to ask a simple question from this domain.

- > My website is "First Page" on Google.

Or

- > My website is "Page One" on Google.

Which one of these is right?

Comment: You've put the two words inside quotation marks and capitalized them. By stylistic convention, this signals that it's a proper name. It could be anything at all between the quotation marks. *My website is "Incredible Panda" on Google.* If you remove the quotation marks, and put the words into lowercase, then the answers already provided here make sense.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this can help you : "My website is on the first page of google search results"

Comment: Hi Mahdi! I believe this answer could be greatly improved if you explain why you think this wording is better than the ones proposed by the OP. Just a bare "try this" isn't likely to be very helpful.

Comment: As far as I can remember, being on the first page of google search results were used in cases like this.

Comment: So your argument is that it's a very common wording, which is actually a pretty solid argument. But it's best if you [edit] that into your answer, with some evidence, such as [results from a corpus](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/727/how-to-use-corpus), sometimes even the number of Google results that turn up for a search can be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of these properly convey what I think you want to say, because it is ambiguous.

If you want to say you outperform all other sites for a particular search,

- My site is the top Google result for XYZ
- My site is the highest ranked result for XYZ in Google
- My site outperforms all other sites for a particular search

If you want to say your site is on the first page of Google's search results for XYZ,

- My site is among the top Google results for XYZ
- My site is on the first page of Google's search results for XYZ

If you want to rank your suggested phrases, I would say "(the) first page" is more idiomatic than "page one" in most contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the privilege to work with SEO in my past. We used to say -

> Our website is on the first page of the ***SERPs*** (Search Engine Result Pages)

Hope this may work.

However, as the other answer says, there could be many ways to tell that.